# How to Convert Custom Controller to Standard Controller, I want to add VFP to Page layout, can anyone please help me with this

Tags: visualforce, wrapper-class, custom-controller

```html
<apex:page controller="TrainingDeal" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlock id="pg">
         <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listWrapper}" var="Wrap">
                <apex:column >
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Wrap.checkBool}"/>
                </apex:column>
             <apex:column value="{!Wrap.T.name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Wrap.T.Course__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Wrap.T.Trainer_Appointed__r.id}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Wrap.T.Trainer_Appointed__r.First_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Wrap.T.Trainer_Appointed__r.Last_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!Wrap.T.Trainer_Appointed__r.Education__c }"/>
                
             
             </apex:pageBlockTable>
            
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

```java
public class TrainingDeal {
    public list<WrapperClass> listWrapper {get;set;}
    public TrainingDeal (){
        List<Training_Deal__c> listT =[select name,Course__c, Trainer_Appointed__r.id, Trainer_Appointed__r.First_Name__c, Trainer_Appointed__r.Last_Name__c,
            Trainer_Appointed__r.Education__c  From Training_Deal__c WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];
        if(listT.size() >0){
            listwrapper = new list<WrapperClass>();
            
            for(Training_Deal__c T: listT){
                listwrapper.add(new WrapperClass(T) );
            }
        }
    }
    
    public class WrapperClass{
        public Boolean checkBool {get;set;}
        public Training_Deal__c T {get;set;}
        public Wrapperclass (Training_Deal__c T){
            this.t=t;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [Edit] your question to include that information. If you have absolutely no idea where to start, you should be looking at documentation for and examples of controller extensions (i.e. your current controller should become a controller extension).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your constructor to accept a standard controller.

```
public TrainingDeal(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
  // Deal with loading record data
}
```